# Vertically centering font in Segmented Controller

Tags: ios

For some reason, the font in my segmented control is not vertically centered. Is there a way to move the font up to be centered vertically?

[image: Screenshot]

The only settings I'm putting on them are below (except for declaring the active/inactive/divider images):

```
NSDictionary *normalSegmentedControlAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                  [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                  [UIFont fontWithName:kFont size:kSegConFontSize], UITextAttributeFont,
                                  nil];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:normalSegmentedControlAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSDictionary *selectedSegmentedControlAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                    [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                    [UIFont fontWithName:kFont size:kSegConFontSize], UITextAttributeFont,
                                    nil];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:selectedSegmentedControlAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: try to set `contentVerticalAlignment`